# getting different values when inspecting an object with gdb

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, stack, segmentation-fault

I'm using gdb to debug a c++ program which terminated with a segmentation fault. Looking at the stack, the first few frames are:

```
 #0  0x0041c496 in cDefaultList::doInsert (this=0x9c69708, obj=0x9c69348) at cdefaultlist.cc:119
#1  0x0041c86c in cDefaultList::take (this=0x9c69708, obj=0x9c69348) at cdefaultlist.cc:189
#2  0x0043bd9c in cPacket::encapsulate (this=0x9c69708, msg=0x9c69348) at cmessage.cc:589
#3  0x08448861 in MobIPv6mn::handleMessage (this=0x96d3350, msg=0x9c69348) at src/networklayer/numbatIPv6/mip6.cc:170
#4  0x0046069c in cSimulation::doOneEvent (this=0x87f3318, mod=0x96d3350) at csimulation.cc:627
#5  0x0015ecdf in Tkenv::doRunSimulation (this=0x87f3110) at tkenv.cc:529
#6  0x0015e899 in Tkenv::runSimulation (this=0x87f3110, mode=2, until_time=..., until_eventnum=0, until_msg=0x0, until_module=0x0) at tkenv.cc:402
#7  0x00168f10 in run_cmd (interp=0x8842e48, argc=2, argv=0xbfffcb00) at tkcmd.cc:430
```

So I do:

```
frame 3
```

and later want to inspect "msg" with `print * (IPv6 *) msg`, because that's what the type of msg should be.   Well, when I look at the Ipv6-specific fields of msg, I always get completely different values, like:

`srcIP_var = {addr = "\000\000\000\000\000\000i\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\001"}, dstIP_var = {
    addr = "\000\000H\223\306\t\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"}, BindingUpdate_var = false, BindingAck_var = false, Dhcpv6Relay_var = false}`

or

`srcIP_var = {addr = "\000\000\000\000\000\000)\000\000\000\020\264K\000\020\264"}, dstIP_var = {addr = "\346\t:SCALEEXP_UNIN"}, BindingUpdate_var = 73, 
  BindingAck_var = 84, Dhcpv6Relay_var = 73}`

or even:

`srcIP_var = {addr = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\061\000\000\000\030\264K\000\030\264"}, dstIP_var = {
    addr = "K\000\a\350N\v\304\350N\v\001\000\000\000\001"}, BindingUpdate_var = false, BindingAck_var = false, Dhcpv6Relay_var = false}`

Why is that? Does that mean the packet is not really of the type I tried to cast it to?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're not just looking at uninitialized (or freed and then re-used) memory? That could explain why your code is crashing as well.

Comment: That might indeed be the case. I just ran valgrind and it said that execution with the same stack I described above resulted in:
`==10112== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==10112== Invalid write of size 4
==10112==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==10112== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==10112==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0`
Any tips on what I should do next?

Comment: There's at least one variable in your program which you are using without initializing. Note that C and C++ do NOT initialise built-in types to zero/null. For example, if you just write "int x; return x;" then you'll return an undefined number. Similarly, "int *px;" is an undefined pointer.

Comment: The casting I was doing was actually wrong! msg was never an IPv6 *. Sorry for the confusion, and thanks a lot for your help!